# select(): What's the reason for incrementing the 'nfds' argument by 1?

Tags: c, select

The Linux man-page of select() says, that the first argument "nfds" of select() has to be **the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.**
What I already know, is that this argument is used for shortening the lookup of the changed file descriptors. (because there is no need for iterating over all FD_SETSIZE-elements..)

But I'm wondering why you have to manually increment this value by **1**.
I mean, why isn't this done by the function itself? Why can I not just pass the value of the highest file descriptor (without increment)?

Comment: It's confusing, I know.  Think of it like this:  If you have the array `int a[8]`, meaning its indices for from `a[0]` to `a[7]`, why is it that you have to add 1 when you write `for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) a[i] = 0;`